# Deploy with Visual Studio Team Services from separate front-end/back-end repositories

Tags: asp.net, single-page-application, git-submodules, git-subtree, azure-pipelines

My team is doing a single-page application that is served from an ASP.NET application, which is deployed via Team Services (was Visual Studio Online).

However, using the **same** Git repository for front-end and back-end code – with the standard `wwwroot` directory – poses some problems with tooling and project structure; it becomes messy.

The team would have better separation of concerns, and not least would it allow for a more standardized repository structure, both for back-end and front-end code, if we had two separate repos.

Is it possible to separate the front-end code out into its **own repository** (which would have a standard build setup, the result of which goes in `wwwroot`), but then deploy **both** repositories as a single application with Team Services?

Is this a job for Git Submodule or Subtree?

Or perhaps the front-end could be packaged as an NPM module that is pulled into the .NET repository on each version change?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup two builds, one for front-end and one for the back-end, then use Release Management to grab the build artefacts from both builds by adding two artefact sources, then deploy them in two individual deployment steps.

Comment: I'll look into Release Management, thanks. I've edited my question with a new option – NPM. Any thought on this?

Comment: You could do that. Or make it a nuget package to be more in line with the standard Microsoft technology. But in that case you'd still have 2 builds

Comment: @dalgard I'm having the exact same issue. I've not tried it with release management yet as I doubt that it is able to orchestrate the results of two separate builds. May I ask how you ended up? My idea was to create an integrational project which has the two others as git submodules. But the the question is whether builds are triggered automatically when either of them is pushed to.

Comment: @jessehouwing ahh yea I see, it alsk about "Artifacts" on the linking page. I will test it. Just need to create my builds... thanks for the hint.